# why I can not ping the specific host name in /etc/hosts under Mac OS Yosemite 10.10.1?

Tags: linux, macos

I add a subdomain into file /etc/hosts:

```
0.0.0.0 localhost.lan group1.localhost.lan group2.localhost.lan
```

and then in the terminal:

```
ping localhost.lan
```

I got the error msg:

```
ping: sendto: No route to host
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
```

But in my another machine with `Fedora Linux 20`, it can work well!
I don't know what software I install in my linux let ping to work, or Mac OS has other rules?

Any advice will be welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Mac OS X, `0.0.0.0` does not point at `localhost` as on Linux.  If you point it at `127.0.0.1` or `::1`, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `0.0.0.0/8` is a [reserved address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses#Reserved_IPv4_addresses) that's used to broadcast messages to the current network. According to **[RFC 1700](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1700)** it can only be used as a source address, not as a destination.

Comment: The Linux IP stack makes 0.0.0.0/8 equivalent to 127.0.0.0/8 when used as a destination address.  BSD-derived network stacks don't.

Comment: Good to know. Either way, it seems like a bad choice as a substitute for the standard loopback address. @abelard20008 why not just use `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: It's not the standard loopback address.  It just behaves as the loopback address on Linux when used as the destination address.  Given that, according to the RFC, 0.0.0.0 should never be used as a destination address, it's the implementers' choice what it does (or doesn't) do.  BSD stacks point it nowhere.  Presumably there are stacks that point it at the default route.  The standard loopback address will always be `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: @PhilipPaeps I think I should have made myself more clear: What I meant is that IMHO it is a bad choice to use `0.0.0.0/8` addresses for whatever purpose the OP may have in mind. Given that - as you say - it is an implementation detail whether these addresses are being routed or not.